# How to copy a column from a file to another empty file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am trying to copy a whole specifit column from a csv file to an empty csv file. My code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
#path_1.csv is the original csv file having the contents I want to copy
src_wb = pd.read_csv(r"path_1.csv")
#path_2.csv is an empty csv file
dest_wb = pd.read_csv(r'path_2.csv')

#Getting the column named "Desc" from the original file
src_sheet = material_library_read["Desc"]
#Getting the first column in the empty file
dest_sheet = dest_wb.iloc[:, 0]

#Inserting the column named "Desc" in path_1.csv into the first column in path_2.csv
dest_wb.insert(0, src_sheet)

#Saving path_2.csv after the copy complete.
dest_sheet.save
```

However, it keeps showing the error of "No columns to parse from file (which means path_2.csv)". The path_2.csv is an empty file. Why does it have such an error? Please help me finding the bug.

Comment: why not `src_sheet = pd.DataFrame( material_library_read["Desc"] )` - and later write it `src_sheet.to_csv(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv is empty, then evidently it has no columns, which is why you get the error message. You seem to expect a quasi-empty `DataFrame` to be generated from `dest_wb = pd.read_csv(r'path_2.csv')`, but an empty `df` of course wouldn't have a first column either (`dest_sheet = dest_wb.iloc[:, 0]`).

In general, the key words used for the variables are rather confusing here. E.g. `src_wb = pd.read_csv(r"path_1.csv")`, why `wb`, when we're dealing with a `csv` read into a `df`? Similarly, `dest_sheet = dest_wb.iloc[:, 0]`; why `sheet` if you want to capture a `column`?

I'm not sure how this line is supposed to execute: `src_sheet = material_library_read["Desc"]`.

Here's a bit of generic python code to open a src_csv, select 1 column and save it to another csv:

```
import pandas as pd

file_source = "source.csv"
file_dest = "dest.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_source)

#'column1' being the name of your column 
series_col = df.loc[:,'test1'] 

# series to csv as column (without index) and saves csv
series_col.to_csv(file_dest, index=False)
```